# $l$-adic integer, reduction map, surjective map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_l$ be an completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ at prime number $l$(i.e, $l$-adic number)

Its ring of integer is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_l$(i.e, $l$-adic integer)

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_l$

Then known fact is that residue field of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_l}$ is algebraic closure of
$\mathbb{F}_l$

So we have a natural reduction map $\overline{\mathbb{Z}_l}\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{F}_l}$(Here, $\overline{\mathbb{Z}_l}$ is a ring of integer of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_l}$)

I saw that in some paper which says $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}\hookrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{Z}_l}\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{F}_l} $ is surjective map. Is it true?(second map is obviously surjective but whole map is surjective?)

Anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Every monic integer polynomial splits completely in $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ whence so it does in its image in $\overline{\Bbb{F}_l}$.

Comment: @reuns Then why above map is surjective?

Comment: Come on I just proved that the image is *algebraically closed*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you buy that $\overline{\mathbb Z}$ is dense in $\overline{\mathbb Z_l}$, then this is obvious: For any $a\in \overline{\mathbb Z_l}$, we can find $b\in\overline{\mathbb Z}$ such that $b-a\in\mathfrak m$ where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal idea of $\overline{\mathbb Z_l}$, and it follows $a+\mathfrak m=b+\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Thank you very much!